# How to read hdf5 dataset with unknown datatype in c?

Tags: c, hdf5

I'm trying to open an hdf5 dataset in c without knowing the dataset type. I can get the dataset type using "H5Dget_type(dataset_id)", however, when I want to allocate memory to the data array, i.e. "datatype(int, float, etc.) dset[n]", I cannot do it without knowing the datatype(int, float, etc.).

So, my question is that how can I get the data type in order to use it to allocate memory to the array which I'm going to use?

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to a particular tool, check out [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as this will alleviate you from low-level details when dealing with HDF5 files. Your problem may be solved using HDFql in C as follows (assume you  want to read dataset `my_dataset`):

```
// declare variables
void *data;
long long size;

// get size (in bytes) of dataset "my_dataset" and populate HDFql default cursor with it
hdfql_execute("SHOW SIZE my_dataset");

// move HDFql default cursor to first position
hdfql_cursor_first(NULL);

// retrieve size (in bytes) from HDFql default cursor
size = hdfql_cursor_get_bigint(NULL);

// allocate memory based on the size (in bytes) of dataset "my_dataset"
data = malloc(size);

// register variable "data" for subsequent usage
hdfql_variable_register(&data);

// select (i.e. read) data from dataset "my_dataset" and populate variable "data" with it
hdfql_execute("SELECT FROM my_dataset INTO MEMORY 0");

// from this point on, variable "data" contains the data from "my_dataset"
```